# Como fazer o telerik RadHtmlChart ser responsivo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Possuo 3 gráficos `RadHtmlChart` do `Telerik` em uma página, estou dividindo essa página em 3 para que eles fiquem sempre exibidos, sem a necessidade de rolar um `scroll` para visualizá-los.

Preciso que ao redimensionar a página, o `RadHtmlChart` se adeque a este redimensionamento.
É possível fazer isso ?

Tentei o seguinte:

```
 window.onresize = function () {
         $find("<%=chtPESO.ClientID%>").get_kendoWidget().resize();
         $find("<%=chtPARTIC.ClientID%>").get_kendoWidget().resize();
         $find("<%=chtVDA.ClientID%>").get_kendoWidget().resize();
 }
```

Porém sem nenhum resultado.

Tentei também utilizando o `@media screen`, porém sem sucesso também.

Como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar as funções `set_width` e `set_height` para fazer o redimensionamento do gráfico.

Você só precisa calcular as dimensões adequadas para preencher toda a tela.

```js
function adjustChartSize(chartClientId, width, height) {
   var chart = $find(chartClientId);

   if (chart) {
      chart.set_width(width);
      chart.set_height(height);
   }
}

window.onresize = function () {
   adjustChartSize("<%=chtPESO.ClientID%>"   , 300, 400);
   adjustChartSize("<%=chtPARTIC.ClientID%>" , 300, 400);
   adjustChartSize("<%=chtVDA.ClientID%>"    , 300, 400);
}
```